# "Have to split" in the film "The Running Man"

Tags: phrase-meaning, jokes, cinema

In the film *[The Running Man](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093894)* (1987), Arnold Schwarzenegger cut a man into two halves. His name was Buzz Saw. Then another man said: "Where did Buzz Saw go?" And Arnold Schwarzenegger said: "He had to split." In the cinema people laughed to hear this, but I don't understand why.

Comment: It's a pun on the word "split".

Comment: If he didn't recognize the pun immediately, telling him it's a pun isn't likely to help him -- he presumably doesn't know the slang meaning of _split_.

Comment: It's hard to explain puns to kleptomaniacs because they're always taking things, literally.

Comment: Just in case others are misled: this is a joke/troll account that asks silly and deliberately disingenuous questions that nonetheless require a bit of lateral thinking to locate the actual jokes.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's a pun on the word "split", vs. the idiom "to split". In English, a common, informal expression is "having to split" for "having to leave". (This comes from *leaving* a group of people being effectively the same as *splitting off* from them.)

The verb split itself, of course, can mean to be literally split into two halves.

In this case, we had a pun because the man (Buzz Saw) was **split** into halves. Another man asks where Buzz Saw went (implying that Buzz Saw is absent at this point, i.e. has left). Schwarzenegger says that Buzz Saw has left (**he had to split**). Unbeknownst to the asker, however, Schwarzenegger also literally split Buzz Saw in two.

Comment: Obligatory: http://i.stack.imgur.com/eHl71.jpg

Comment: Thank you Mr/Mrs Newb! Now I can enjoy to watch the film every way - the graet acting, fiting and also funy things!

Comment: +1 for "unbeknownst"... I have to use that more often.